# Real Estate Google Map Widget

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I need this map widget on my real estate website. I have seen it on few of the websites but I'm unable to find this widget by googling. The link to one of the sites where this widget is available is below

www.rebeccalaing.ca/Search_Toronto_Real_Estate_Listings

Or the widget on redfin.com.. 
http://www.redfin.com/homes-for-sale#!lat=42.53686494220565&long=-71.00828000000001&market=boston&v=6&zoomLevel=13

Please if anyone can tell me where can I get this widget.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean the whole thing and not just the map itself - stuff like this is usually custom-built, and unable to get as a widget. You will probably need to hire somebody to build it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are these so called "widgets" are custom made implementations of (google) maps.

I don't think any of these can be found anywhere to download, let alone be 'plug-and-play' since these widgets require one or more back-end webservices to supply their data.

I have written one such 'widget' myself, and I strongly suggest you to do the same if you really need this. You should use [the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) for the map stuff, and maybe [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for the GUI itself

Answer (score 1):

It's [Google Maps API V.3](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/), with a lot of customizations: overlays, marker images, layers...

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it a proprietary widget that you can't just buy/download, but you also need legal agreements from the real estate brokerages (who own the listing data) in order to display the listings.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft can probably set you up with their map that is customized for real estate. http://www.microsoft.com/maps/industry/realestate.aspx